# %5C being inserted into url

Tags: php, redirect, character-encoding

I am currently working on a site where there is a search box. when we run a query in the search box which contains an apostrophe, the application escapes the ' character with a back slash. when the search box runs a query for men's the url should read `www.example.com/products/search?q=men%27s`. Instead it reads

> www.example.com/products/search?q=men%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C ... %5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%27s.

on our live server this problem occurs but when ran locally when in development the url is formulated as required. I am running PHP 5.4 locally and PHP 5.3 on the live server. we have looked at various php.ini settings and apache config settings and we are unable to identify the issue. Has anybody got any ideas?

I'm running apache 2.4.9 locally and 2.2 on live server.

Thanks

Comment: can you say what programming language escapes the character? what language are you using and what code are you using, because the code is clearly in a loop here. We can't help you unless we know what tools you're using

Comment: I use php 5.4 locally and 5.3 on the server. When a query contains an apostrophe the string is url encoded and appended to a request url which is sent to our api. At this point, on the live server the problem occurs. URL: /products/search&api_key=xxxxxxxxx&q=men%27s. We thought the explanation would involve php version differences between server and local. Locally the urlencode is replacing with the urlencoded value for an apostrophe (%27). when run on the server it is replacing with the value for \ (%5C) which would suggest a config issue or php version issue. we cannot work out what it is.

Comment: I'm running apache 2.4.9 locally and 2.2 on live

Comment: I have updated your question

Comment: Can you show the PHP code you use that actually translates the %27 back to the ' character? Cheers

Comment: your php code that translates the `$_GET['q']` is clearly in a loop of translating the slash